# Producer-Consumer pattern not suitable for our app? Or just a misunderstanding of usage?

Tags: linux, multithreading, performance, design-patterns, networking

I am maintaining a linux server application which is multithreaded and written in C++. There are about 10 modules, and tens of std::deques there for message-passing purpose. The application uses Producer-Consumer pattern to pass network packets between modules.

The Producer-Consumer design pattern acts well in many situations, however I don't think it is suitable for our application. See below flow chat in Pseudocode:

```
   CSocketModule (for receiving and sending packets)
   CSockMod::ReceivePackWorkerThread --> CSockMod::Inque -->                    
   CSockMod::InqueWorkerThread --> CSomeMod::Inque -->
   CSomeMod::InqueWorkerThread --> Generates Response Packets -->
   CSomeMod::Outque --> CSomeMod::OutqueWorkThread --> //Optional
   CSockMod::Outque --> CSockMod::SendPackWorkerThread --> 
   Linux Kernel::TCP/UDP Layer

   For each module, there would be two std::deques for buffering 
   in/out pakets, two working threads for processing incoming and 
   outgoing packets respectively.
```

Because almost every Inque and Outque will be accessed by more than two threads when running, thus there must be many many pthread_mutex_locks to synchronize these queues. But, these locks will make the application act like a single-thread software. As a server application, this is not likely to be acceptable.

Meanwhile, suppose there are 1000 packets in CSomeMod::Inque and the 1000th packet is a controlling packet from a client, then the client has to be waiting until the CSomeMod::InqueWorkerThread have processed the 999 packets in the Inque. Controlling commands might be greatly delayed!

So, the Producer-Consumer pattern is not suitable for our application? Or there is misunderstanding in using this pattern here? I appreciate any help, thanks!

Steve

Comment: As an architecture question, this may get better answers on [programmers.se].

Comment: Your current architecture is okay, just make sure that your threads don't hold the locks for any significant amount of time.  In particular, lock the mutex, pull an item out of the dequeue (or even pull all of the items out of the dequeue!), unlock the mutex, and then process the items afterwards (i.e. while the mutex is unlocked) so as not to block any other threads for very long.

Comment: @JeremyFriesner But how do we deal with the problem in the last two paragraphs? The problem isnot a real problem?  Problem-----"suppose there are 1000 packets in CSomeMod::Inque and the 1000th packet is a controlling packet from a client, then the client has to be waiting until the CSomeMod::InqueWorkerThread have processed the 999 packets in the Inque. Controlling commands might be greatly delayed!"

Comment: @StevePeng do what John Zwinck said, use a separate queue for "high priority" commands where FIFO-ordered processing isn't sufficient.  Then check that queue after processing each regular-priority command to make sure that no new high-priority commands have arrived.

Comment: @JeremyFriesner Thanks so much, I would have accepted your answer if you don't write it as comments:_) It's closed as off topic, but acutally I dont quite understand. I posted it here because it has desgin pattern tag!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two easy things you can try to directly address your concerns:

1. Replace your std::deques plus pthread_mutexes with a single-producer, single-consumer lock-free queue like this: http://www.1024cores.net/home/lock-free-algorithms/queues/unbounded-spsc-queue or this: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/boost/lockfree/spsc_queue.hpp
2. Create additional queues for high-priority items where needed.  Always check these queues first.

You didn't mention whether any of this is a problem in practice currently.  In any case: profile, profile, profile.

Comment: I want to try lock-free queue.